# How do I make python read a value after a string, then comparing and outputting the value?

Tags: python

For example, say I have a set of data.txt:

```
Name1 | Points:100
Name2 | Points:150
Name3 | Points:200
```

I want python to read the value after "Points:", compare it to a variable "j" and output the line only if the value is less than the variable "j".

I'm a complete beginner to Python, so apologies if this seems very easy. Thanks for any replies :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may use this:

This code reads all the lines from the file and iterates them one by one. we find the location where the number begins and we convert it from string to int to compare.

```
path = "some/path/to/file.txt"
with open(path, "r") as datafile:
    lines = datafile.readlines()

j = 150
for row in lines:
    row = row.replace("\n", "")
    num_start = row.find(":") + 1
    # get chars from num_start till the end and convert to int
    point = int(row[num_start:])
    print(point)
    if point > j:
        print(row)
```

Comment: There is no need to manually search the delimiter or remove whitespace. ``point = int(row.split(':', 1)[1])`` works directly on rows read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
file1 = open('data.txt', 'r') 
file_lines = file1.readlines()
for line in file_lines:
    points = (int)(line.split(':')[1])
    if points < j:
        print(points)

file1.close()
```

First you read the file. This is what lines 1 and 2 are doing. Line 3 allows you to iterate through the file, one line at the time.

Now we can move to next part which "read" the points in every line. To do that I used `split` method.It separates the line into a list by the char ':'. Taking it [1] argument means "take whatever is after the first ':' and before the next ':'" (which does not exist in our case).. An hidden assumption is that there is only one ':' in each row, and points follows by it.
Then you have in points the value of current line, you can compare it as you want.

For next time: when asking a question in stackoverflow, give a code example of what you already tried, what and did not work and concrete examples of input and output.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I'm using the piece of code and I'm getting a syntax error on this line: 
`if ((int)points) < j:` specifically the `)p` part

Comment: @Fast sorry, I made an small edit: move casting from if compression to assignment a line earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re
    text = open('data.txt')
    line = text.readline()
    while line:
        out = re.findall('\d+', )
        line = text.readline()
        if out < j:
            print(out)
    text.close()
```

Hope this helps.